# Error when load images in angular2 after having uploaded them in sails 404 not found

Tags: node.js, angular

when I load an image in sails I return the address where it is saved to visualize it but I get GET http://localhost:1337/images/user/cb8a85c7-3af6-49c1-a8cb-d42ae2fcab9d.jpg 404 (Not Found) but the image is correctly loaded in these path

.ts

```
formData.append('image[]', inputEl.files.item(0));
  this.ajax.imageUp(formData).subscribe(dataImage=>{
    this.data.user.image = dataImage.json()['image'];
  });
```

ajax

```
imageUp(data: any){
return this.http.post('user/imageup',data,{});}
```

userController.js

```
imageUp: function (req,res) {
req.file('image[]')
  .upload({
    maxBytes: 1000000, // Files limit(in bytes)
    dirname: path.resolve(sails.config.appPath, 'assets/images/user') // Path to copy the files
  }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFiles) {
    if (err) {
      // here must delete the created user before the error
      return res.serverError(err);
    }
    var image_real_name = 'images/user/'+path.basename(uploadedFiles[0].fd);
    res.json({image: image_real_name});
  });}
```

in html

```
<img src="{{data.user.image}}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must be missing this line in your server/index.js

```
app.use(express.static('assets'))
```

For more detail, please read :

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html